# How to inject indexed (and class specific) strings using Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I've been hacking with Google Guice a bit lately and I came up with an idea to inject a `String` to a constructor according to the class it is being declared in and other several parameters defined in an annotation. For example:
If I define a new qualifier annotation `@NamedInjectable` to be used by Guice:

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Qualifier
public @interface NamedInjectable
{
    String name() default "";

    boolean indexed() default true;
}
```

Where name is a new name base for the string (default is only the class' name), and `indexed` states whether or not the name should be incremented each time a new string is being injected.
e.g.

```
public MyClass {
    @Inject
    public MyClass(@NamedInjectable(name = "foo", indexed = true) String name) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

And `name` param should be given a value such as "
I considered using *Provider Bindings* or *AssistedInject* but I could get it done. One main reason to failing, is somehow getting the name of the class.

Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to customize a standard Guice binding based on names. If you want to stick to Guice alone, you'll probably need [Custom Injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections).

> In addition to the standard @Inject-driven injections, Guice includes hooks for custom injections. This enables Guice to host other frameworks that have their own injection semantics or annotations. Most developers won't use custom injections directly; but they may see their use in extensions and third-party libraries. Each custom injection requires a type listener, an injection listener, and registration of each.

Guice's documentation example for Custom Injections demonstrates a logger instance customized with the type of the injecting class, which sounds very much like something you want to do—it's no more difficult to read the parameters of the annotation you create from within your TypeListener. However, this doesn't work directly with @Inject annotations or constructors, so you may have trouble if you're trying to make the injection happen entirely behind the scenes.

Another option is much simpler: Just use a factory and pass in the newly-constructed class.

```
public MyClass {
    private final String name;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(NameInjector nameInjector) {
        this.name = nameInjector.get(this, "foo", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I find the factory injection much more suitable to my purposes. Though it seems like an overkill =)

Answer (score 1):

For ordinary Guice injections, you can't access the name of the class where the something is being injected. If you really need to do that, you would need to use custom injection.

By using a custom `TypeListener`, you can listen for injection events and know the class that is being injected. On hearing an injection event, you can register a custom `MembersInjector` that Guice will invoke *after* it finishes its own injections. This `MembersInjector` has access to the fully-constructed instance of the class, so it can reflect on fields and inspect annotations. However, it obviously can't inject constructor parameters, since the object has already been created.

In short, there is no way to do custom injection of constructor parameters. But the idea you describe is very possible for field injection!

**How to do it**

First, you need to register a `TypeListener` (this code based on the linked Guice wiki page):

```
public class NamedStringListener implements TypeListener {
    public <T> void hear(TypeLiteral<T> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<T> typeEncounter) {
        Class<?> clazz = typeLiteral.getRawType();
        while (clazz != null) {
             for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
             if (field.getType() == String.class &&
                 field.isAnnotationPresent(NamedInjectable.class)) {
                     Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(NamedInjectable.class);

                     // How you create and configure this provider is up to you.
                     Provider<String> provider = new MyStringProvider(clazz, annotation);
                     typeEncounter.register(new MyMembersInjector<T>(field, provider));
                 }
             }
         clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
         }
     }
}
```

Then, inside `MyMembersInjector<T>`:

```
public class MyMembersInjector<T> implements MembersInjector<T> {
    final Field field;
    final Provider<String> provider;

    NamedMembersInjector(Provider<String> provider) {
        this.field = field;
        this.provider = provider;
        this.field.setAccessible(true);
    }

    public void injectMembers(T t) {
         field.set(t, provider.get());
    }
}
```

I leave the implementation of `MyStringProvider` up to you.

See the [Guice CustomInjections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) wiki page for more.

Comment: Thnx. I have already tried CustomInjections. As I understood, Field injections are not encouraged for different reasons (leaving `final` fields out...)